# Normalize planes of 4D kernel density estimation to unity

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density

I have a `4D PDF P(x, y | a, b)` which I am trying to characterize using kernel density estimation with known data points `[x, y, a, b]`. Each plane `(x, y)` should normalize to unity. However the data is sparse and not every x-y plane in my 4D grid has known data points a, b.

I initially used `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to estimate a density across the 4D space, however this results in the 4D space normalizing to unity, not just a plane. Is there a way to normalize each plane now that I have the overall shape of the distribution? Or is this a completely incorrect approach.

Comment: Could you show some code/data?!